# Explaining the Church-Rosser Theorem in basic terms

Tags: lambda, sml, operator-precedence

I would like to know how the Church-Rosser theorem is used within programming, specifically functional programming. I've looked up information but can only find sources referring to lambda calculus (limited knowledge) and beta-reductions.

If anyone could explain where lambda calculus comes into this and what reductions are, I think that would clear things up.

My initial thoughts of the Church-Rosser theorem is that it's to do with order of evalutation and execution of functions but I'm not entirely sure whether this is accurate information.

Thanks.

Note: I'm currently studying Standard ML

Comment: I don't think that the Church-Rosser theorem has direct practical uses if by "practical use" you mean something you explicitly use when writing code. It does have practical implications about how functional programs can be easily parallelized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial thoughts are fine.

- The lambda calculus is the formal foundation on which functional programming is built.
- The lambda calculus is a term rewriting system, and a [reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Reduction) means following a rewrite rule.
- The lambda calculus does not dictate a specific order of evaluation, so given a lambda expression where multiple reductions are possible, the Church-Rosser theorem says that you can pick either one. This gives functional programming language designers quite a lot of freedom to design their evaluation semantics. For example, in *f (g x)*, assuming both are pure functions, whether you reduce *f* or *g* first are equivalent.

  Wikipedia's description of the [Church-Rosser theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Rosser_theorem) is:

  > [I]f there are two distinct reductions or sequences of reductions that can be applied to the same term, then there exists a term that is reachable from both results, by applying (possibly empty) sequences of additional reductions.

  The example *f (g x)* where *f* is *x²* and *g* is *2x*:

  ```
  (λx.x*x) ((λy.y+y) 2)  ~β~>  ((λy.y+y) 2)*((λy.y+y) 2)
                         ~β~>  (2+2)*((λy.y+y) 2)
                         ~β~>  (2+2)*(2+2)

  (λx.x*x) ((λy.y+y) 2)  ~β~>  (λx.x*x) (2+2)
                         ~β~>  (2+2)*(2+2)
  ```

  In this example, the two distinct reductions are β-reduction on either of the lambdas, and one term among others that is reachable from both reductions is `(2+2)*(2+2)`.

Comment: Thanks very much!  This makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: Would you mind showing a practical example of church-rosser in a functional programming language? If you could that would be great thanks :)

Comment: How about this? The best functional language for this example is simply the lambda calculus. :) You can replace `λx.y` with `fn x => y` for a translation to Standard ML.

Comment: Yeah that's good thanks. So in very simple terms, church-rosser theorem essentially states that an expression can be evaluated via different paths and still have the same result no matter which path is chosen?